# Can not reach local DNS server for local dot domain subzones because firewall returns gateway IP

Tags: dns, nat, pfsense, named

I have pfSense inline between my cable modem and my switch, on pfSense I have a NAT port forward on 53 to my local DNS server which I want to serve local subzones to the LAN with. Right now when I dig the local nameserver, it is returning my gateway's IP and expecting my WAN IP.

**USING PUBLIC IP**

```
dig @ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com
```

returns:

```
;; reply from unexpected source: 192.168.1.41#53, expected 72.28.137.79#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 192.168.1.41#53, expected 72.28.137.79#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 192.168.1.41#53, expected 72.28.137.79#53

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

with 192.168.1.41 being my firewall/gateway

```
dig ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com
```

returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55005
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com. 299 IN    A   72.28.137.79

;; Query time: 75 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 15 18:01:12 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 62
```

**USING INTERNAL IP**

```
dig ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com
```

returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16525
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;;  QUESTION SECTION:
;ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com. 299 IN    A   192.168.1.35

;; Query time: 86 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 15 18:03:53 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 62
```

`dig @ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com`

returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Some Additional dig commands

```
$ dig @kara.ns.cloudflare.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @kara.ns.cloudflare.com www.local.jeffreylroberts.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58910
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.local.jeffreylroberts.com. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
local.jeffreylroberts.com. 300  IN  NS  ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-local.jeffreylroberts.com. 300 IN    A   72.28.137.79

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245.58.123#53(173.245.58.123)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 16 12:48:11 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86

$ dig @8.8.4.4 www.local.jeffreylroberts.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.4.4 www.local.jeffreylroberts.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 21237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.local.jeffreylroberts.com. IN  A

;; Query time: 3163 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 16 12:48:30 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

It appears to work just fine from kara.ns.cloudflare.com but not from google

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this is greatly appreciated.